# How to cleanly close connection in Netty if ChannelOutboundBuffer is filled?

Tags: netty

After calling `channel.disconnect()` in Netty 4.x I've got a bunch of the following exceptions:

```
io.netty.channel.StacklessClosedChannelException: null
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.close(ChannelPromise)(Unknown Source) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
```

They are probably created because `ChannelOutboundBuffer` is not empty.

How to clean `ChannelOutboundBuffer` before `close()` ?

How to avoid them or maybe I should catch them and ignore (if there is no way to avoid them) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`close()` should "clean" the `ChannelOutboundBuffer`, which means it will fail all the writes that are still sitting in there with a `ClosedChannelException`. This sounds totally normal.

Comment: Thanks Norman again!  I found a way to clean `ChannelOutboundBuffer` just before disconnect(): ```while (channel.unsafe().outboundBuffer().remove()); ``` . But because it goes through unsafe() method I don't feel comfortable with it. Does this way have some undesirable side effects ?

Comment: You shouldn't do this.... as this basically will succeed all writes. This is not correct as if you close the channel while writes where not done yet it should fail these with an exception (which is what happened).

Comment: Ok - so basically doing this I will lose a possibility to identify which messages was eventually sent and which was not.
The correct way is to mark this channel as TO_BE_CLOSED state, then handle exceptions in handlers exception callback . Even if handling means ignoring StacklessClosedChannelException if TO_BE_CLOSED is flagged.